# .contains giving empty string in rdd

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an array of id's called id. I have an RDD called r which as a field called idval which might have some ids in the id array. I want to get only the rows which are in this array. I am using

```
val new_r = r.filter(x => r.contains(x.idval)
```

But, when I go to do

```
new_r.take(10).foreach(println)
```

I get a `NumberFormatException: empty String`

Does contains include empty strings?

Here is an example of lines in the RDD:

```
idval,part,date,sign
1,'leg',2011-01-01,1.0 
18,'arm',2013-01-01,1.0 
6, 'nose', 2011-01-01,1.0
```

I have a separate array with id's such as [1,3,4,5,18,...] and I want to extract the rows of the RDD above which have the idval in ids

So filtering this should give me

```
idval,part,date,sign
1,'leg',2011-01-01,1.0 
18,'arm',2013-01-01,1.0
```

as idval 1 and 18 are in the array above.

The problem is that I am getting this empty string error when I go to foreach(println) the rows in the new filtered array.

The RDD is loaded from a  csv file (loadFromUrl) and then its mapped

```
val r1 = rdd.map(s=>s.split(","))

val r2 = r1.map(p=>Event(s(0), p(1),dateFormat.parse(p(2).asInstanceOf[String]), p(3).toDouble))
```

Comment: I assume you do val new_r = r.filter(x => ids.contains(x.idval)).  what are the types here? NumberFormatException: empty String suggests you have both a string and a number...

Comment: Can you post a [mcve], please? There's nothing in the two lines you post that would cause a `NumberFormatException`. Your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Hey guys I added more info thanks!

Comment: In other words, what @TheArchetypalPaul means is how do you obtain your RDD r that you are filtering on ? Please post the real related code. That code contains a typo to start with and it also uses an RDD in the filter which is incorrect and which would never give the error you are mentioning.

Comment: Almost certainly, there's a line in there that's not in the format you expect. The `foreach{println}` isn't directly causing the problem. Spark is lazy and doesn't evaluate things until it has to, so the `foreach` is forcing evaluation, loading your RDD and converting it. So we need to see the code that creates the RDD (but as I sau, I think you'll find there are errors in  your data)

Comment: Sorry there is more info

Comment: I think its a cleaning data problem. Is there a good way to remove empty strings in the data, there are some empty strings in the rdd when it was created from the data

Comment: Either I'm missing the point, or it's obvious - just `rdd.filter(s.nonEmpty)` before the first map. Also, the "C" in [mcve] is important. Not sure what the `asInstanceOf[String]` is about, either.